# How to use FlexTable with UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I want to create this simple static layout:

[image]

but unfortunately I cannot find a description on how to do that with a `FlexTable` (or something else). This can't be done with a simple `Vertical*` or `HorizontalPanel` since the alignment of the labels and textboxes would not be correct that way.

Is there a way to do something like this in the UiBinder:

```xml
<x:TableView>
  <x:TableRow>
    <x:TableCell><g:Label ../></xTableCell>
    <x:TableCell><g:TextBox ../></xTableCell>
  </x:TableRow>
  <x:TableRow>
    <x:TableCell><g:Label ../></xTableCell>
    <x:TableCell><g:TextBox ../></xTableCell>
  </x:TableRow>
  <x:TableRow>
    <x:TableCell><g:Label ../></xTableCell>
    <x:TableCell><g:CheckBox../><g:CheckBox../> .. </xTableCell>
  </x:TableRow>
</x:TableView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `<table>` in a `<g:HTMLPanel>`, or probably better, use `<div>`s with CSS (flexbox comes to mind).

```xml
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>…</label></td>
    <td><g:TextBox/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>…</label></td>
    <td><g:TextArea/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>…</label></td>
    <td><g:CheckBox/><g:CheckBox/>…</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It turns out that one may use bare HTML inside `ui.xml` files - I didn't know that :D